# How to perform the same operation(s) on all elements in a list

Tags: r

I have a large list with 317 elements. Each element contains a varying number of cases. These elements all have the exact same categories, but they have different numbers for all of them.

Each element has five categories:

- Location
- Species 1 count
- Species 2 count
- Species 3 count
- Total species count

I originally had a dataframe that had all of the records in one, but I split it based on location as I am trying to find the proportion of the three species for each site (hence the 317 elements. There were 317 different locations so it split them into that)

I just want to perform the same operation on every element, receiving a number for each of them. I don't know how to calculate the proportion, but I do not need help with that. I just want to perform the same function on every single element in the list I have.

This is the code so far that I want to execute for every single element. I need to add the proportions code, but I will do that when I find out how to work it out.

```
##df = name of the large list

    df$location <- df$location[!( ((df$species1) + (df$species2) + (df$species3)) != (df$totalSpecies) ),]
    ##remove any records where the three species do not equal the total
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Could you post data for (say) three locations?  Doesn't have to be your real data, just enough so that someone could carry out the operations you want to do.

Comment: `lapply`, but it's simpler to group or nest your data.frame than split. In base R `aggregate` will take you a ways, but dplyr or data.table make this sort of operation much simpler.

Comment: `Location: A, A, A
Species1: 200, 300, 400
Species2: 100, 0, 0,
Species3: 300, 100, 0
TotalSpecies: 600, 500, 400


Location: B, B, B, B
Species1: 400, 100, 200, 200
Species2: 400, 50, 50, 100
Species3: 100, 0, 500, 300
TotalSpecies: 900, 150, 750, 600


Location: C
Species1: 50
Species2: 100
Species3: 0
TotalSpecies: 0`

Comment: You can process a list using Map, Filter or lapply. _e.g_.
   `c <- [1, 2, 3]`
    `squares <- unlist(Map(fun<-function(x) x*x, c))`

Comment: This won't help with applying a function to a list, but you may have been able to get the proportions by location fairly easily in the original dataframe using the dplyr library. Assuming you minimally had three columns, Location, Species, and Count, you could do something similar to this with the original dataframe. `df <- df %>% group_by(Location) %>% mutate(LocTotal = sum(Count)) %>% ungroup() %>% mutate(Percent = Count / LocTotal * 100)`

Comment: Thank you to everyone who helped! lapply ended up working just fine.